# setText() doesn't seem to work sometimes. Not able to figure out the reason

Tags: android

I am working on school project. setText() method works some times and other times it doesn't seem to do anything. Not able to find out reason. Below is my java class where i am trying to set the values to the view. I can the correct values in log statement below.

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.TextView;


  public class CourseDetail extends Activity{
TextView txtcourse;
TextView txtcoursetitle;
TextView txthours;
TextView txtsession;
TextView txtunits;
TextView txtconditions;
TextView txtdescription;

String course,courseTitle,hours,units,conditions,description,session;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.course_details);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    course = i.getStringExtra("cid");
    courseTitle = i.getStringExtra("name");
    session = i.getStringExtra("session");
    hours = i.getStringExtra("hours");
    conditions = i.getStringExtra("conditions");
    description= i.getStringExtra("description");
    units= i.getStringExtra("units");

    Log.i("Inside coursedetails","coursedetails"+course+"|"+courseTitle+"|"+session+"|"+hours+"|"+conditions+"|"+description);  

    txtcourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.course);
    txtcoursetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coursetitle);
    txthours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
    txtconditions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conditions);
    txtsession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.session);
    txtunits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.units);
    txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

   txtcourse.setText(course);
   txtcoursetitle.setText(courseTitle);
   txthours.setText(hours);
   txtconditions.setText(conditions);
   txtsession.setText(session);
   txtunits.setText(units);
   txtdescription.setText(description);



}



}
```

xml layout.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

  <RelativeLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/customshape"
              android:padding="7px"
              >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tab2_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Courses"
            android:textAlignment="inherit"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:gravity="center" />

          </RelativeLayout>    

     <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >



   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/title1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:background="#cac9c9"
         android:padding="5dp"
         android:text="Course"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/course"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

   </TableRow>



   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title2"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Course Title"
          android:textColor="#040404"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
          android:background="#cac9c9"
           android:padding="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/coursetitle"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

    </TableRow>

   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

     <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Session"
          android:textColor="#040404"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
          android:background="#cac9c9"
           android:padding="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/session"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

   </TableRow>

  <TableRow
   android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
   android:padding="5dp" >

  <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title3"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Hours"
          android:textColor="#040404"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
          android:background="#cac9c9"
           android:padding="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/hours"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

 </TableRow>


 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title4"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Units"
          android:textColor="#040404"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
          android:background="#cac9c9"
           android:padding="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/units"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

   </TableRow>



   <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
          android:id="@+id/title5"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Conditions"
          android:textColor="#040404"
          android:textSize="15dp"
          android:textStyle="bold"
          android:typeface="sans"
          android:background="#cac9c9"
           android:padding="5dp" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/conditions"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_gravity="fill" />

   </TableRow>





  </TableLayout>

  <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

         android:layout_gravity="fill"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:ellipsize="end"
         android:singleLine="false"

         android:textColor="#040404"
         android:textSize="15dp"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:typeface="sans"
         android:padding="5dp" />

      </LinearLayout>

   </ScrollView>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Here is a screenshot of the log

[image]

Here is the screen shot of the detail view

[image]

Case that is working

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors? If so please show your logCat

Comment: Your screen shots seem to indicate a layout/formatting problem, so the `setText`

Comment: So, what does happen? You were pretty clear with your question, just curious for some extra detail. Does the text reset to its default value, go blank, remain the same, etc. Also, does it happen to all at once, or just some?

Comment: Happens only to few records. Some fields get set and some don't. In some other cases everything remains blank, but messes the table layout. As seen in the detail picture i posted. Does this have something to do with tablelayout?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way here is demo example u have to modify as per ur requirement.

**1. activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tab2_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Courses"
        android:textAlignment="inherit"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:gravity="center" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Course"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/course"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Course Title"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coursetitle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Session"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/session"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hours"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hours"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title4"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Units"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/units"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title5"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Conditions"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:background="#cac9c9"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/conditions"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**2. MyActivity**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    TextView txtcourse;
    TextView txtcoursetitle;
    TextView txthours;
    TextView txtsession;
    TextView txtunits;
    TextView txtconditions;
    TextView txtdescription;

    String course,courseTitle,hours,units,conditions,description,session;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        course = i.getStringExtra("cid")==null?"Demo Course":i.getStringExtra("cid");
        courseTitle = i.getStringExtra("name")==null?"Demo Name":i.getStringExtra("name");
        session = i.getStringExtra("session")==null?"Demo Session":i.getStringExtra("session");
        hours = i.getStringExtra("hours")==null?"Demo Hours":i.getStringExtra("hours");
        conditions = i.getStringExtra("conditions")==null?"Demo Conditions":i.getStringExtra("conditions");
        description= i.getStringExtra("description")==null?"Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions Demo Descriptions":i.getStringExtra("description");
        units= i.getStringExtra("units")==null?"Demo Units":i.getStringExtra("units");

        Log.i("Inside coursedetails", "coursedetails" + course + "|" + courseTitle + "|" + session + "|" + hours + "|" + conditions + "|" + description);

        txtcourse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.course);
        txtcoursetitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coursetitle);
        txthours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        txtconditions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.conditions);
        txtsession = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.session);
        txtunits = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.units);
        txtdescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);

        txtcourse.setText(course);
        txtcoursetitle.setText(courseTitle);
        txthours.setText(hours);
        txtconditions.setText(conditions);
        txtsession.setText(session);
        txtunits.setText(units);
        txtdescription.setText(description);
    }
}
```